# No reverse match. Ideas how to fix?

Tags: python, django, path, templating

Can anyone figure out why I'm getting a ***no reverse match*** error here:

`urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ReservationsFormView.as_view(), name='reservations'),
    path('edit/<slug:pk>/', EditReservationView.as_view(), name="edit_reservation"),
    path('reservation_complete/', ReservationCompleteView.as_view(), 
name="reservation_complete"),
    path('reservations_account/', ReservationAccountView.as_view(), 
name="reservations_account"),
    path('delete/<slug:pk>/', DeleteReservationView.as_view(), 
name="delete_reservation"),
]
```

It's only happening, so far, on my `edit/delete` paths (the one's with the `<slug:pk>`)

`views.py`:

```
class ReservationsFormView(CreateView):
    model = Reservations
    template_name = "reservations/reservations.html"
    form_class = ReservationForm
    success_url = "reservation_complete/"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)


class EditReservationView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    form_class = ReservationForm
    template_name = 'reservations/edit_reservation.html'
    success_url = "/reservations_account/"
    model = Reservations

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user == self.get_object().user


class ReservationCompleteView(CreateView):
    template_name = "reservations/reservation_complete.html"
    success_url = "/reservation_complete/"
    form_class = ReservationForm
    model = Reservations


class ReservationAccountView(ListView):
    template_name = "reservations/reservations_account.html"
    model = Reservations

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = {
            'reservations': self.model.objects.filter(user=self.request.user),
        }
        return context


class DeleteReservationView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    """ A view to delete an reservation """
    model = Reservations
    success_url = "/reservations_account/"

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user == self.get_object().user
```

`Models.py` File:

```
class Reservations(models.Model):

    """ reservation form categories and attributes """
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phoneNumberRegex], 
max_length=16, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.CharField(choices=time_options, default="12pm", 
max_length=10)
    number_of_party = models.IntegerField(choices=party_size, 
default=1)
    reservation_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, 
default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

Corresponding Html is:

```
<button href="{% url 'edit_reservation' reservation.id %}" type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Edit</a>
<button href="{% url 'delete_reservation' reservation.id %}" type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Delete</a>
```

Error Message:

```
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'delete_reservation' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['reservations/delete/(?P<pk>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']
```

Really hoping it's something simple.
Any help is appreciated.
If you need to see more code, let me know and i'll update with what's needeed.

Comment: do you sure reservation.id is not empty?

Comment: Added the models.py file. Shows the reservation.id should be generatinag a unique number, or so i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Django sees you’ve explicitly set `Field.primary_key`, it won’t add the automatic `id` column.
So you should use `pk` or `reservation_id`.
also `pk` is more independent from the actual primary key field i.e. you don't need to care whether the primary key field is called `id` or `reservation_id` or whatever.

```
<button href="{% url 'edit_reservation' reservation.reservation_id %}" type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Edit</a>
<button href="{% url 'delete_reservation' reservation.reservation_id %}" type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Delete</a>
```

### or use pk:

```
<button href="{% url 'edit_reservation' reservation.pk %}" type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Edit</a>
    <button href="{% url 'delete_reservation' reservation.pk %}" type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Delete</a>
```